# How can I identify "groups" of sequential numbers in an array (PHP)?

Tags: php, arrays

I have been searching high and low for an answer to this problem. Everything I have found so far is *close* to what I need, but not quite. I just can't seem to find the right combination of keywords to search for.

I have an array defined with missing keys, like this (the keys are automatically generated from other data and could be anything, although they will always be in order from lowest to highest):

```
$Array = array(
    1 => "A",
    2 => "B",
    4 => "C",
    7 => "D",
    8 => "E",
    9 => "F",
    12 => "G",
    15 => "H",
    16 => "I"
);
```

I need to create another array that detects each group of sequentially-numbered keys, like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 9
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 16
        )
)
```

Keys "4" and "12" will be discarded, since "5" and "13" respectively don't exist.

How can I achieve this?

I have tried every combination of for, foreach, and while loop iteration I can think of. I always end up with completely messed up, overly long arrays looking like

```
[ . . . ]

[16] => Array
    (
        [0] => 7
        [1] => 8
        [2] => 9
    )

[19] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4
    )

[21] => Array
    (
        [0] => 7
        [1] => 8
        [2] => 9
    )

[27] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8
        [1] => 9
    )

[30] => Array
    (
        [0] => 9
    )

[33] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8
        [1] => 9
    )

[ . . . ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking of a better way, but this works:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($Array as $k => $v) {
    if(isset($Array[$k+1])) {
        $result[$i][] = $k;
        $result[$i][] = $k+1;
        $result[$i] = array_unique($result[$i]);
    } else {
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: No it doesn't.  All of the keys are read by the foreach and the key is the value of `$k`.

Comment: Oh my mistake. Retracted, apologies.

Comment: I did find a bug but no time to troubleshoot, so I edited and added `array_unique`. Not optimal.

Comment: Atleast put your `array_unique` into the else branch before increasing the index.

Comment: @ccKep: Why don't you try that and tell me how it works out :-)

Comment: @AbraCadaver [Link](http://codepad.org/DnSR8u6t) There you go. And don't start me on using the suppression prefix because you don't declare your arrays in the first place ;) Edit: You could aswell just fix the double-adding by checking `$Array[$k-1]` aswell.

Comment: Works great coupled with array_unique. This returns just what I wanted. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Glued this together, needs further testing though:

```
$Array = array(
    1 => "A",
    2 => "B",
    4 => "C",
    7 => "D",
    8 => "E",
    9 => "F",
    12 => "G",
    15 => "H",
    16 => "I"
);

$ret = array();
$cur = array();


print_r($Array);

$prevKey = NULL;
foreach($Array as $k => $v)
{
    if (!isset($prevKey) || $k - $prevKey == 1)
    {
        $cur[] = $k;
    } else {
        $ret[] = $cur;
        $cur = array();
        $cur[] = $k;
    }
        $prevKey = $k;
}
if (count($cur) > 0)
    $ret[] = $cur;

print_r($ret);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => A
    [2] => B
    [4] => C
    [7] => D
    [8] => E
    [9] => F
    [12] => G
    [15] => H
    [16] => I
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 9
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 16
        )

)
```

Comment: You can simply loop through that and discard sub-arrays with only 1 entry aswell.

Comment: Apparently I don't have enough reputation to upvote. I went with AbraCadaver's answer but I'm definitely saving this one in the back of my mind. As I get further I might end up finding that I need those extra lone keys instead of discarding them.

Answer (score 0):

It's to specific to have an existing PHP function about it. This should generate the results in the way that you specified...

```
$Array = array(
    1 => "A",
    2 => "B",
    4 => "C",
    7 => "D",
    8 => "E",
    9 => "F",
    12 => "G",
    15 => "H",
    16 => "I"
);
$lastNum = -1;
$sequences = array();
$curSequence = array();
foreach($Array as $arrayIndex => $arrayValue){
    if($arrayIndex == $lastNum + 1 || $lastNum === -1){
        //Is sequential...
        $curSequence[] = $arrayIndex;
    }else{
        //Non-sequential...
        if(count($curSequence) > 1){
            //Add current sequence
            $sequences[] = $curSequence;
        }
        //Start a new sequence
        $curSequence = array($arrayIndex);
    }
    $lastNum = $arrayIndex;
}
//At the end of the loop, store current sequence
if(count($curSequence) > 1){
    $sequences[] = $curSequence;
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($sequences); echo "</pre>";
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 9
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 16
        )

)
```

Answer (score -1):

The question is tagged PHP but here's a Java solution if anyone is interested

```
import java.util.*;


public class FindSequential {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Map<Integer, String> inputMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
    inputMap.put(1,"A");
    inputMap.put(2,"B");
    inputMap.put(4,"C");
    inputMap.put(5,"D");
    inputMap.put(8,"E");
    inputMap.put(9,"F");
    inputMap.put(12,"G");
    inputMap.put(15,"H");
    inputMap.put(16,"I");
    inputMap.put(18,"J");
    inputMap.put(20,"K");
    inputMap.put(21,"L");

    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> outputList = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();
    int previousKey = -1;
    int outputListIndex = 0;
    List<Integer> tempList = null;
    for (int key: inputMap.keySet()) {
        if(previousKey == -1) {
            // first element
            previousKey = key;
            tempList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            continue;
        }
        int diff = key - previousKey;
        if(diff == 1) {
            // continuous sequence
            if(!tempList.contains(previousKey)) {
                tempList.add(previousKey);
            }
            if(!tempList.contains(key)) {
                tempList.add(key);
            }
            outputList.put(outputListIndex,tempList);
        } else {
            // not a sequence
            if(tempList.size() > 0) {
                outputListIndex++;
            }
            tempList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        }
        previousKey = key;
    }
    // you can print the outputList here
  }
}
```

Comment: Down voted why? Is the solution wrong? I thought users are encouraged to contribute. Wasn't expecting an up vote but a down vote was disappointing

Comment: Since the OP specifically asked for a solution in PHP, it's doubtful that a Java solution would be helpful to him/her.

Comment: @DavidGorsline true. Lesson learnt. Will not post alternate solutions from now on.